# Looping Over JSON Data with jQuery

Tags: jquery, json

I'm working in Coldfusion but in this scenario, it shouldn't matter.

I'm retrieving some json formatted data (see below) and I need just the names (it's for an autocomplete form field).  I need the other data which is why it's being included here but if I can get help pulling out the name, I think I can manage the other bits of info for later on in the form.

The problem I'm having is my autocomplete is not populating with the name value returned from the json data.  I know it has something to do with the way I'm referencing the values but I don't know where the break down is located.

This is what I have in my success function:

```
var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < j.features.length; i++){
        options += '<option value="' + j.features[i].attributes.name + '">' + j.features[i].attributes.name+ '</option>';
        }
```

this is what I'm seeing in the console log window  - json formatted data -

```
    {
    "displayFieldName": "name",
    "fieldAliases": {
        "name": "name"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "name",
            "length": 150
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sheltering A"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -8614890.23598794,
                "y": 4526897.651595688
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sheltering L"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -8644978.888800403,
                "y": 4504316.305944032
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: but what's your question / problem?  are you stuck with something?  is something there not working?  what do you need help with?

Comment: thescientist - Sorry about that.  Question has been updated.  My autocomplete is not displaying the NAME values returned from the json object.

Comment: is that all you have in your function?  Where are you appending these options to the DOM?

Comment: any error in your browser console

Comment: Did you parse the JSON?  Can you set a breakpoint in your browser?  After the loop, does the string of options look correct?

Comment: to anyone running across this SO question:  there are no errors and I did not include the part where the results are added back to the DOM since those are working as expected.  If I return just text from the ajax call, the content is placed in the container div;  to keep the question clear and concise, I left out that part of the JS function.  There were no errors thrown.  I could dump the entire json object to the container, I just wasn't able to display ONLY the piece I wanted, specifically the names, which ultimately filled in the autocomplete form field.  Thanks everyone for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this,

In this data contains array of dictionary, In this case I took `data[0]` you can find out the length using data.length then get the `data[i]`.

[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/6Y68N/)

```
data = [{
    "displayFieldName": "name",
    "fieldAliases": {
        "name": "name"
    },
    "geometryType": "esriGeometryPoint",
    "spatialReference": {
        "wkid": 102100
    },
    "fields": [
        {
            "name": "name",
            "type": "esriFieldTypeString",
            "alias": "name",
            "length": 150
        }
    ],
    "features": [
        {
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sheltering A"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -8614890.23598794,
                "y": 4526897.651595688
            }
        },
        {
            "attributes": {
                "name": "Sheltering L"
            },
            "geometry": {
                "x": -8644978.888800403,
                "y": 4504316.305944032
            }
        }
    ]
}]

var options = '';
    for (var i = 0; i < data[0]['features'].length; i++){

        options += '<option value="' +data[0]['features'][i].attributes.name + '">' +data[0]['features'][i].attributes.name+ '</option>';
        }
alert(options)
```

**Update:**
http://jsfiddle.net/dhana36/6Y68N/1/